# Substitute specific letters in a string during letter substitution without knowing letter index?

Tags: javascript, html, substitution

I'm working on this simple JavaScript application that takes plain text and uses a substitution cipher to scramble the text and generate the output. Basically a 'made-up language' generator. Some consonants end up next to each other and makes it difficult to pronounce smoothly. For example `'throughout'` translates to `'jpviompioj'`.

Would it be possible to check for situations where `'jpv'` is present in the substituted text and alternatively substitute it with `'z'` to ultimately print `'ziompioj'` but check in a way so that if I don't know the index of these specific consonant groupings it will still use the alternative substitution?

The substitution code I'm currently using is as follows:

```
function Translate()
        {
            var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
            var substitute = "ufdrabmpetqzswigkvxjolcynhUFDRABMPETQZSWIGKVXJOLCYNH "
            var text = document.getElementById('txtEnglish').value;
            var translated = '';

            messageArr = text.split('');

            for(i in messageArr)
            {
                index = alphabet.search(messageArr[i]);
                translated += substitute[index];                
                document.getElementById('txtOutput').value = translated;
            }   
        }
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: @PrerakSola How would the examples in the link you suggested be implemented in my substitution code?

Comment: @PrerakSola Nevermind, I figured it out. Thanks :)